# Extract last row cell reference using excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How to return the cell reference of the last row of data present in a column?

I want to pass it as input to index match. I tried using the combination of Address and counta. It returns a string and I am unable to pass it to index-match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LOOKUP function us ideal for this. For example:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A<>""),A:A)
```

- (A:A<>"") returns an array {TRUE,TRUE,....,FALSE}
- 1/(A:A<>"") modifies that array to achieve {1,1,..,#DIV/0!,..}.
- Since LOOKUP expects to see an array sorted (in ascending order), and if it cannot find an exact match, it will choose the largest value in the *lookup_range* that is less than or equal to the value (in this example two), So the formula finds the last "1" in the array and returns the corresponding value from the *result_range*.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked for you